# How to prompt for target-specific Makefile variable if undefined?

Tags: variables, makefile

This is similar to [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298890/read-makefile-variable-from-console-if-not-set), but I only want `make` to prompt for a value if I'm running a *specific target* and a mandatory variable has not been specified.

The current code:

```
install-crontab: PASSWORD ?= "$(shell read -p "Password: "; echo "$$REPLY")"
install-crontab: $(SCRIPT_PATH)
    @echo "@midnight \"$(SCRIPT_PATH)\" [...] \"$(PASSWORD)\""
```

This just results in the following output and no prompt:

```sh
Password: read: 1: arg count
@midnight [...] ""
```

The important point here is that I have to ask *only* when running this target, and *only* if the variable has not been defined. I can't use a `configure` script, because obviously I shouldn't store passwords in a config script, and because this target is not part of the standard installation procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that Makefiles don't use Dash / Bash-style quotation, *and* that Dash's `read` built-in needs a variable name, unlike Bash. Resulting code:

```sh
install-crontab-delicious: $(DELICIOUS_TARGET_PATH)
    @while [ -z "$$DELICIOUS_USER" ]; do \
        read -r -p "Delicious user name: " DELICIOUS_USER;\
    done && \
    while [ -z "$$DELICIOUS_PASSWORD" ]; do \
        read -r -p "Delicious password: " DELICIOUS_PASSWORD; \
    done && \
    while [ -z "$$DELICIOUS_PATH" ]; do \
        read -r -p "Delicious backup path: " DELICIOUS_PATH; \
    done && \
    ( \
        CRONTAB_NOHEADER=Y crontab -l || true; \
        printf '%s' \
            '@midnight ' \
            '"$(DELICIOUS_TARGET_PATH)" ' \
            "\"$$DELICIOUS_USER\" " \
            "\"$$DELICIOUS_PASSWORD\" " \
            "\"$$DELICIOUS_PATH\""; \
        printf '\n') | crontab -
```

Result:

```sh
$ crontab -r; make install-crontab-delicious && crontab -l
Delicious user name: a\b c\d
Delicious password: e f g
Delicious backup path: h\ i
no crontab for <user>
@midnight "/usr/local/bin/export_Delicious" "a\b c\d" "e f g" "h\ i"
$ DELICIOUS_PASSWORD=foo make install-crontab-delicious && crontab -l
Delicious user name: bar
Delicious backup path: baz
@midnight "/usr/local/bin/export_Delicious" "a\b c\d" "e f g" "h\ i"
@midnight "/usr/local/bin/export_Delicious" "bar" "foo" "baz"
```

This code:

- treats all input characters as literals, so it works with spaces and backslashes,
- avoids problems if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without writing anything,
- uses environment variables if they exist, and
- works whether crontab is empty or not.

Answer (score 2):

l0b0's answer helped me with a similar problem where I wanted to exit if the user doesn't input 'y'. I ended up doing this:

```
@while [ -z "$$CONTINUE" ]; do \
    read -r -p "Type anything but Y or y to exit. [y/N] " CONTINUE; \
done ; \
if [ ! $$CONTINUE == "y" ]; then \
if [ ! $$CONTINUE == "Y" ]; then \
    echo "Exiting." ; exit 1 ; \
fi \
fi
```

I hope that helps someone. It's hard to find more info about using user input for an if/else in a makefile.

Comment: Unless mine eyes deceive me, that while loop will repeat rather than use the default `N` if you simply press Enter.

Comment: You should use a [single equals sign in `[`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Conditionals)

Comment: You can also simplify the `if` statement: `if [ $$CONTINUE != "y" ] && [ $$CONTINUE != "Y" ]; then`. Or even `[ $$CONTINUE = "y" ] || [ $$CONTINUE = "Y" ] || (echo "Exiting."; exit 1;)`